# Getting Graph and Block Animation to Run Smoothly Together

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have been working on some code that produces a live graphic of a graph and blocks moving. It works in theory but does not look like how I want. The animation runs very slow when showing both the graph and the blocks together (a code of each alone works much better). How can I get them to work together smoothly?

I am also open to any other advice regarding this code on how I can improve its readability, speed, and functionality.

Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import keyboard
import pandas
 
# =============================================================================
# Parameters
# =============================================================================
time = 10  # maximum time for the simulation
h = 0.05  # step size
steps = int(time/h)  # number of steps
order = 4  # two second order equations
 
ICs = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]  # intial conditions; t0, x1, x1dot, x2, x2dot
m1 = 1.0  # kg; mass 1
m2 = 3*m1  # kg; mass 2
k = 3.0  # N/m; spring constant
F = 2.8  # N; forcing force
us = 0.5  # static friction coefficient
uk = 0.3  #k inetic friction coefficient
g = 9.81  # m/s^2; gravity

side1 = m1  # side length of mass 1
side2 = m2  # side length of mass 2

parameters = {'m1':m1, 'm2':m2, 'k':k, 'F':F, 'us':us, 'uk':uk, 'g':g}
units = {'m1':'kg', 'm2':'kg', 'k':'N/m', 'F':'N', 'us':'', 'uk':'', 'g':'m/s^2'}

# For logging the data to a CSV
All_Values = {'t':[], 'x1':[], 'v1':[], 'x2':[], 'v2':[]}

# =============================================================================
# Intializing Arrays
# =============================================================================
vars = np.empty(shape=(order,steps))  # each row is another var, i.e. x1,x2,...
 
# Set initial conditions for each var
for i in range(order):
    vars[i][0] = ICs[i+1]
    
K = np.zeros(shape=(4,order)) # Each row is k1, k2, k3, k4 for each var
t = np.empty(steps)
t[0] = ICs[0]

# =============================================================================
# Resets the arrays
# =============================================================================
def setup():
    global K
    # Initializing vars array
    vars = np.empty(shape=(order,steps))  # each row is another var, i.e. x1,x2,...
     
    # Set initial conditions for each var
    for i in range(order):
        vars[i][0] = ICs[i+1]
        
    K = np.zeros(shape=(4,order)) # Each row is k1, k2, k3, k4 for each var
    t = np.empty(steps)
    t[0] = ICs[0]

# =============================================================================
# ODE function
# =============================================================================
def ODE(t, var, varsprev):
    # variables are as defined in the 'parameters' dict
    m1 = parameters['m1']
    m2 = parameters['m2']
    k = parameters['k']
    F = parameters['F']
    us = parameters['us']
    uk = parameters['uk']
    g = parameters['g']
    
    # spring force based on the initial and current length of the spring
    l_eq = vars[2][0] - vars[0][0]  # equilibrium length
    l_current = var[2] - var[0]
    F_s = k*(l_current - l_eq)
    
    # static friction until it can no longer fight the spring force
    static = m1*g*us
    kinetic = m1*g*uk
    if F_s <= static:
        F_f = F_s
    else:
        F_f = kinetic
        
    dx1dt = var[1]  # v1 = x1dot
    
    # Adjust the sign of friction
    # c = 0, no friction; c = 1, friction left; c = -1, friction right
    c = 1  # assume friction left unless if-else below says otherwise
    # if the block is moving to the left, friction to the right
    if var[1] < 0:
        c = -1
    # if the block isn't moving, depends on direction of spring force
    elif var[1] == 0:
        # spring pushing left, friction to the right
        if F_s < 0:
            c = -1
        # no velocity nor spring force, no friction
        elif F_s == 0:
            c = 0
    dv1dt = 1/m1 * (F_s - c*F_f)
    
    dx2dt = var[3]  # v2 = x2dot
    
    # chose that mass 2 does _not_ experience friction
    dv2dt = 1/m2 * (-F_s + F)
    
    return(np.array([dx1dt, dv1dt, dx2dt, dv2dt]))

# =============================================================================
# Plotting function
# =============================================================================
plt.ion() # set interactive mode on 
fig, (graph, block) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(8,10))

fig.suptitle(f'Double Spring Mass with Partial Friction Using RK4 (stepsize: {h})',
             y=0.94)

def Plotting(i):
    # GRAPH
    graph.cla()  # clear what is currently graphed
    graph.plot(t[:i], vars[0,:i], label=f'x1')
    graph.plot(t[:i], vars[1,:i], label=f'v1')
    graph.plot(t[:i], vars[2,:i], label=f'x2')
    graph.plot(t[:i], vars[3,:i], label=f'v2')
    
    graph.annotate(f'time = {round(t[i],1)}s', xy=(0.5, 0.98), 
                 xycoords='axes fraction', ha='center', va='top')    
    
    graph.set_title('Graph')
    graph.set_xlabel('time [s]')
    graph.set_ylabel('position [m]')
    
    graph.legend(loc=2)  # upper left

    # =========================================================================
    # BLOCKS
    block.cla()  # clear what is currently graphed
        
    m1x = vars[0][i]
    m2x = vars[2][i]
    
    COM = (m1*(m1x-side1) + m2*(m2x+side2))/(m1 + m2)   
    windowOffset = abs(max((m1x-side1) - COM, (m2x+side2) - COM, key = abs))+side2
    
    block.set_xlim(-(COM+windowOffset),COM+windowOffset)
    # plt.ylim(0,1.5*side2)
    
    mass1 = patches.Rectangle((m1x-side1,0), side1, side1, facecolor='#1f77b4')
    
    mass2 = patches.Rectangle((m2x, 0), side2, side2, facecolor='#ff7f0e')
    
    # Spring color based on length from equilibrium
    l_eq = ICs[3] - ICs[1]  # equilibrium length
    l_curr = m2x - m1x  # current length of spring
    
    if (l_curr == l_eq):
        c = 'k'
    elif (l_curr > l_eq):
        c = '#d62728'
    else:
        c = '#2ca02c'
    
    spring = patches.ConnectionPatch(xyA=(m1x,side1/2), coordsA = 'data',
                                     xyB=(m2x, side1/2),coordsB='data',
                                     linewidth = 2,
                                     color = c)
    
    block.add_patch(spring)
    block.add_patch(mass1)
    block.add_patch(mass2)
    
    block.axis('equal')
    
    block.annotate(f'time = {round(t[i],1)}s', xy=(0.5, 0.98), 
                  xycoords='axes fraction', ha='center', va='top')
    
    block.set_title('Block Animation')
    block.set_xlabel('Position [m]')
    
# =============================================================================
# User parameter change
# =============================================================================
def paramUpdate(i):        
    update = True
    
    # print parameters and values
    def printParams():
        print("\nCurrent parameters and values: ")
        
        for j in parameters:
            print(j, '=', parameters[j], units[j])
    
    changed = False  # if a parameter is changed, this ensures plot resets
    while update==True:
        try:
            printParams()
            # ask for parameter to change
            key = input("Which parameter would you like to change? (or type \"n\" to resume plotting) ")
            
            # if 'n', resume plotting from the current i
            if key == '' or key == 'n':
                return (-1 if changed else i)
            
            # check to see if the parameter exists (i.e. key exists)
            if key not in parameters.keys():
                raise KeyError
            
            # if the value is not convertable to float, throws 'ValueError'
            value = float(input("What is the new value? "))
            
            parameters[key] = value  # change the parameter value
            
            printParams()
            changed = True  # a change has been made; plot will reset
            
            while True:
                resume = input("Would you like to continue changing parameters? [y/n] ")[0].lower()
                if resume == '' or not resume in ['y', 'n']:
                    print("Please answer with 'y' or 'n'. ")
                else:
                    update = True if resume == 'y' else False
                    break
        # catching errors
        except KeyError:
            print("\nPlease enter a valid parameter.")
        except ValueError:
            print("\nPlease enter a valid value.")
    return -1
        
    

print('Press \"z\" to pause')
print('Press \"c\" to resume')
print('Press \"x\" to save and quit')
print('Press \"v\" to adjust parameters')



# =============================================================================
# main loop that calculates each var value using RK 4th order method
# =============================================================================
pause = False
i=0
while i<(steps-1):
    if i == 0:
        setup()
    
    # calculates each k value
    K[0] = h * ODE(t[i],       vars[:,i],          vars[:,i-1])
    K[1] = h * ODE(t[i] + h/2, vars[:,i] + K[0]/2, vars[:,i-1])
    K[2] = h * ODE(t[i] + h/2, vars[:,i] + K[1]/2, vars[:,i-1])
    K[3] = h * ODE(t[i] + h,   vars[:,i] + K[2],   vars[:,i-1])
    
    # combines k values using RK4 method
    vars[:,i+1] = vars[:,i] + 1/6 * (K[0] + 2 * K[1] + 2 * K[2] + K[3])
    
    # updates time
    t[i+1] = t[i] + h
    
    # Plotting every fourth calculation to speed up plotting
    if (i%4 == 0):
        Plotting(i)
        fig.canvas.draw()
        plt.pause(0.01)
    
    # exit
    if keyboard.is_pressed('x'):
        plt.pause(0.01)
        break
    
    # update parameters
    if keyboard.is_pressed('v'):
        i = paramUpdate(i)
        
    # pause and resume
    if keyboard.is_pressed('z'):
        pause = True
    while pause:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('c'):
            pause = False
        if keyboard.is_pressed('x'):
            plt.pause(0.01)
            break
        if keyboard.is_pressed('v'):
            i = paramUpdate(i)
            pause = False
        
    i+=1

print("Done")
 
plt.show()
# plt.close()  # closes the plot at then end


# Saving values to a CSV
All_Values['t'] = t
All_Values['x1'] = vars[0]
All_Values['v1'] = vars[1]
All_Values['x2'] = vars[2]
All_Values['v2'] = vars[3]

df = pandas.DataFrame(All_Values)

df.to_csv('Value_Output.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EmboKQH8lM    Please watch this. Start from 18:54 to cut the irrelevant stuff.